# Get request with supertest parsing issue

Tags: javascript, express, jestjs, supertest

I am using supertest to test get requests to mLab app. If I do a regular GET request with postman I receive this:

```
{"_id":"5b169a9951573c50d9682d52","text":"First test note","title":"Test1"}
```

But the response received in the test adds slashes before each quote:

```
{\\"_id\\":\\"5b169a9951573c50d9682d52\\",\\"text\\":\\"First test note\\",\\"title\\":\\"Test1\\"}
```

This is my test file:

```
const server = require("../../app/server");

const request = require("supertest")(server);

describe("routes: index", () => {

  test("should respond as expected", async() => {

    const app = request("http://localhost:8000");

    const response = await app.get("/notes/5b169a9951573c50d9682d52");

    expect(response).toEqual("First test note");

    expect(response).toEqual("Test1");

  });

});
```

This is my server

```
const express = require('express'); // node module 
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const db = require('./config/db');

const app = express();

const port = process.env.PORT || 8000;

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));

MongoClient.connect(db.testUrl, (err, database) => {
  if (err) return console.log(err)
  require('./routes')(app, database);
  app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('We are live on ' + port);
    console.log(process.env.PORT);
  });
})

module.exports = app;
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't been using supertest myself, but a brief look at your code and documentation immediately shows several issues.

First of all, what you see is what your test framework reports to you - it is a string representation of the json object. It is correct.

What is not correct is how you try to handle the response. Check the documentation:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/supertest

I think, you may solve the problem by
1) setting the expected type
2) and by accessing the body member of the response

```
const response = await app.get("/notes/5b169a9951573c50d9682d52").set('Accept', 'application/json');

expect(response.body.text).toEqual("First test note");
```

I hope, this works.